# Solidity: transferFrom can't reach allowance value

Tags: solidity

Here are the steps I follow on Remix:

1. Deploy my ERC20Basic token and my DEX contract.
2. DEX.buy > Buy ERC20Basic tokens in exchange of ETH (works fine).
3. ERC20Basic.approve(contractAddress, tokenAmount) (works fine).
4. ERC20Basic.allowance > Works fine, function returns the amount of the allowance.

The problem comes when I try to sell tokens with this function from my DEX contract:

```
function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");
        
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
        
        emit Sold(amount);
    }
```

I still get "Check the token allowance".

When I log the allowance I get 0.

When I log `msg.sender` and `address(this)`, I get the same addresses I used on the Remix interface to get the value of the allowance manually.

It feels like the allowance is reset to 0 when I call the sell function or that the sell function can't reach the value of the allowance. Maybe this is something about memory and storage?

My allowance function inside of ERC20Basic contract is:

```
function allowance(address owner, address delegate)
        public
        view
        override
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }
```

Approval function:

```
function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens)
        public
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
```

Allowance structure:

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowed;
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the approve function?

In your code you aren't passing the require statement because your approval wasn't successful. If it was your allowance wouldn't be 0.

You are probably calling the approve function from the contract which won't work because then the msg.sender would be address of the contract not your accounts address.

You have to approve the amount manually outside of the contract for it to work.

Comment: I deploy my ERC20 token and my DEX contracts, then call the approve function through the Remix interface ERC20.approve (with the contract as the spender and the amount allowed).
I then check the allowance through the interface again (the wallet address as the owner and the contract as spender) and it is set correctly.

When I log token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this))
msg.sender = account address (the owner of the tokens)
address(this) = address of the spender (contract)
That's when it shows 0

Comment: How did you initialize your token variable?

like this?

TokenName public token = TokenName("tokenAddress");

maybe try to call it with the interface:

uint allowance = IERC20(tokenAddress).allowance("yourAddress", "spendersAddress");

Comment: import "./FrkCoin.sol";
IERC20 public FrkcReserve;

constructor() {
        FrkcReserve = new FrkCoin();
    }

Comment: That is not right. To interact with the contract you have to do it like I showed you in previous comment. If you want to define it in constructor it has to look like this.

`IERC20 public token;`

`constructor(address _tokenAddress) { token = IERC20(_tokenAddress); }`

Then you can call functions on the contract like this:

`token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));`